# Elasticsearch converting a string to number

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to Elasticsearch and am just starting up with ELK stack. I am collecting key value type logs in my Logstash and passing it to an index in Elasticsearch. I am using the kv filter plugin in Logstash. Due to this, all the fields are string type by default.

When I try to perform aggregation like avg or sum on a numeric field in Elasticsearch, I am getting an Exception: `ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]`

When I check the mappings in the index, all the fields except the timestamp ones are marked as string.

Please tell me how to overcome this issue as I have many numeric fields in my log events for aggregation.

Thanks,

Keerthana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In latest Logstash the syntax is as follows

```
filter {
  mutate {
    convert => { "fieldname" => "integer" }
  }
}
```

You can visit this link for more detail: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert

Answer (score 10):

You could set explicit mappings for those fields (see e.g. [Change default mapping of string to "not analyzed" in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483302/change-default-mapping-of-string-to-not-analyzed-in-elasticsearch/27484723#27484723) for some guidance), but it's easier to just convert those fields to integers in Logstash using the [mutate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate):

```
mutate {
    convert => ["name-of-field", "integer"]
}
```

Then Elasticsearch will do a better job at guessing the best data type for your field(s).

(See also [Data type conversion using logstash grok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548994/data-type-conversion-using-logstash-grok/27550597#27550597).)