# Logstash output to ElasticSearch With Valid Types

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, kibana-4

ELK Stack has been successfully setup.

using grokdebug.herokuapp.com

my gork patterns are also valid and getting Dumped into ElasticSearch

```
filter {
  if [type] == "some_log" {
grok {
    match => { "message" => '%{WORD:word_1} %{TIME:time_1} %{DATE:date_1} %{NUMBER:number_1}'
             }
overwrite => "message"
     }
                          }
     }
```

This grok parsing of input is completely correct.

and output is

```
output {
    elasticsearch { 
         protocol => "http" 
                  }
       }
```

Problem is all the dumped variables are of String Type.

How to get them logged into their respective type in ElasticSearch ( Correct Mapping Type)

time_1, date_1 and number_1 all has same type which is of type

```
"time_1":{
    "type":"string",
    "norms":{
        "enabled":false
            },
     "fields":{ 
            "raw":{
                 "type":"string",
                 "index":"not_analyzed",
                 "ignore_above":256
                  }
              }
          }
```

I want date_1 to be indexed as Date Type, number_1 to be indexed as Number type in Elastic search.

PS: Is it possible to do that ?? determine the Type of Elasticsearch field from Logstash.

OR - How to send those field with proper type to ElasticSearch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your grok pattern, use the form `%{PATTERN:field:datatype}` to turn the captured fields into something other than strings. Valid data types are "int" and "float". In your case you'd e.g. use `%{NUMBER:number_1:int}` to turn your number_1 field into an integer.

See the [grok filter documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) under Grok Basics.

Another option is to use the [mutate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate) to convert the type of existing fields:

```
mutate {
  convert => ["name-of-field", "integer"]
}
```

Related:

- [Data type conversion using logstash grok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548994/data-type-conversion-using-logstash-grok/)
- [Elasticsearch converting a string to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297722/elasticsearch-converting-a-string-to-number/).

Comment: Can we do the same for Date and Time ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert all the fields with `ruby` plugin. 
In this example we combine the `time_1` and `date_1` together and convert them to `Date` format.

```
input {
        stdin{}
}

filter {
        grok {
                match => [ "message" , "%{WORD:word_1} %{TIME:time_1} %{DATE:date_1} %{NUMBER:number_1}"]
                        overwrite => "message"
        }
        ruby {
                code => "
                        datetime = event['time_1'] + ' ' + event['date_1']
                        event['datetime'] = Time.strptime(datetime,'%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%Y')
                        event['number_1'] = event['number_1'].to_i
                "
        }
}

output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

If you have another type that need to convert, you can try to find ruby api to convert them. Hope this can help you.